# qooxdoo : How to disable resize of qx.ui.window.Window?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a class that extends `qx.ui.window.Window` .

I managed to show it to screen by the following codes:

```
this.__panel = new my_project.MyPanel();
this.__panel.center();
// then I open it through a button click ( codes irrelevant, omitted )
```

In the constructor of `MyPanel()`, I have the followings :

```
this.base(arguments, "My Panel");
this.setShowMaximize(false);
this.setShowMinimize(false);
this.setWidth(800);
this.setHeight(480);
var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(0,0);
this.setLayout(layout);
this.setContentPadding(0);
```

What did I miss to make it non-resizable ? Did I overlook the API docs ?

Reference: [qx.ui.window.Window](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.window.Window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a `qx.ui.window.Window` non-resizable ( disable resizing ), add this line in constructor:

```
this.setResizable(false, false, false, false);
```

*Note: I'm using qooxdoo v2.1.1*